# How can show textview when result not empty in android?

Tags: android, performance, android-activity

I'm new to android development. I know this one may repeated question but I didn't understood how i implement these methods. I want to show `TextView` when result not empty, I have researched and find some method like `textview.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);` OR `textview.setVisibility(View.GONE);` I'm trying so far but did not get any result.

I have tried this but it is not working properly. Please guide me where i'm wrong.
`String Msg = json1.getString("msg");
resultView.setText("Error :" + Msg);
resultView.setVisibility(View.GONE);`

Comment: what exactly is the problem? From Your description: "I want  to show hide....", so what You want to do? Show or hide the textView?

Comment: @Opiatefuchs Sorry I want to just show when result is not empty..

Comment: Are you sure that resultView is obtaining correct value?

Comment: @LizFalcón Yes i am sure that resultView is obtaining correct value

Comment: Are you on the UI thread? Something tells me you're on a background thread since you are receiving a JSON object.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to do something like these:

```
    if(Msg.equalsIgnoreCase("")) { // OR if(Msg.equals("")) 
        resultView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
   } else{    
        resultView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        resultView.setText("Error :" + Msg);
    }
```

Try it may help you.

Answer (score 0):

Similiar to ULHAS answer, but You can do also:

```
String jsonString = json1.getString("msg");

if(!jsonString.isEmpty()){
rersultView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
resultView.setText("Error :" + Msg);
}else{
rersultView.setVisibility(View.GONE);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
String str = json1.getString("msg");
    if (!str.isEmpty()) {
        rersultView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        resultView.setText("Error :" + Msg);
    } else {
        rersultView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
```